# Android Custom Launcher doesn't stop the BootAnimation

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source, android-launcher, boot-animation

I am working on a custom launcher for Android, in a project using BBBAndroid (android v4.4.4 w/ kernel 3.8 for the beagleboneblack):
http://bbbandroid.sourceforge.net

I created [aosp_stripped.mk](http://pastebin.com/s2cKqnaJ) to strip some unneeded Android packages and replace the Launcher2 and the HOME packages with my CustomLauncher. This launcher is mostly an normal app with the LAUNCHER and HOME category added in its AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.customlauncher" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="test.service.lib"
            android:required="true" />
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It effectively replaces Launcher2, but the boot animation doesn't stop until 40 seconds later, logcat shows:

```
W/WindowManager(  591): ***** BOOT TIMEOUT: forcing display enabled
I/PowerManagerService(  591): Boot animation finished.
```

So my launcher must be missing something to tell the boot animation to stop. I found some hints here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2485118

Indeed, I have some missing Wallpaper classes errors in logcat, but I didn't remove the SystemUI package. I noticed that when using Launcher2/Home, this error only happens on the first boot. Using my custom launcher, it happens on every boot. Besides this error, I didn't find any differences:

```
W/WallpaperService(  591): Attempted wallpaper ComponentInfo{com.android.wallpaper/com.android.wallpaper.fall.FallWallpaper} is unavailable
W/WallpaperService(  591): Failure starting previous wallpaper
W/WallpaperService(  591): Attempted wallpaper ComponentInfo{com.android.wallpaper/com.android.wallpaper.fall.FallWallpaper} is unavailable
E/WallpaperService(  591): Default wallpaper component not found!
```

I found this class in the package LiveWallpapers in packages/wallpapers/Basic (AOSP). It is already added in PRODUCT_PACKAGES, but this package is nowhere in out/target/product/beagleboneblack/ :(

Right now I am digging in Launcher2 and WallPaperManager to see what could trigger the BootAnimation to stop...

Thanks in advance !

**Update**

I also tried to stop the bootanimation using system properties, but the touchscreen is not usable until the `BOOT_TIMEOUT` event:

```
    import android.os.SystemProperties;

    // inside a Service with system privileges
    SystemProperties.set("service.bootanim.exit", "1");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracing the `BOOT TIMEOUT` problem, it comes from WindowManagerService `performEnableScreen()` waiting for a wallpaper to be set/active, the boot isn't considered done otherwise:

```
            // If we are turning on the screen after the boot is completed
            // normally, don't do so until we have the application and
            // wallpaper.
            if (mSystemBooted && ((!haveApp && !haveKeyguard) ||
                    (wallpaperEnabled && !haveWallpaper))) {
                return;
            }
```

I also noticed that the wallpapers apks in packages/wallpapers are not built for the target because the bbbandroid repo lacks opengl support for now.

My current workaround for this problem is to disable the WallpaperService via its internal config.xml file:

```
diff --git a/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml b/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
index 6efb4a4..0c873b7 100644
--- a/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
+++ b/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
@@ -701,7 +701,7 @@
     <string name="default_wallpaper_component" translatable="false">@null</string>

     <!-- True if WallpaperService is enabled -->
-    <bool name="config_enableWallpaperService">true</bool>
+    <bool name="config_enableWallpaperService">false</bool>

     <!-- Whether to enable network location overlay which allows network
          location provider to be replaced by an app at run-time. When disabled,
```

This solution works if you don't mind using modified android sources.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is not with your launcher app, in this case you would see in logcat errors from your app. Usually boot animation hangs when SystemUI can't start (due to a failure).

Launcher app itself doesn't stop boot animation, it doesn't have this functionality.

You probably disabled some critical component which breaks boot workflow. Yes, wallpapers can affect it. I would recommend to put everything back in your .mk file, check that it builds and boots OK, then replace launcher only with your app. Then you can cut mk file further to check which module creates the issue.

I do not remember exactly but `Browser` module may include webview component which is used by many components.

You should post full logcat output, and may be dmesg output as well.

Comment: I understand that removing some modules may break the boot workflow, but in the current state the Launcher2 launcher works. I have found a workaround for this problem and the wallpapers seem to be the problem.

Comment: I see you did good researching with wallpaper service, voting up for your answer. I know about `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml`, I customized it for my ROM too, but I do not remember all things it handles.